# Updating data in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a unique issue. In a table called CRIMINAL sits data of criminal orientation in a column called CHARGE1. But sometimes there is extra data within the table that I'd like to delete. Basically more than one charge, on occasion,  sits in the column such as below:

speeding 75/45 #2 trespassing #3 burglary

etc, etc. Some only have one charge, but many have multiple .

What I would like it to delete everything to the right of, and including #2, so the CHARGE1 table would only have speeding 75/45

There are literally tens of thousands of rows so fixing manually is not an option :( Thank you in advance

Comment: Basically you want to `UPDATE Criminal SET Charge1 = SUBSTRING(CHARGE1,1, CHARINDEX( '#', CHARGE1)) WHERE CHARINDEX( '#', CHARGE1) <> 0` for columns which have more than one charge

Comment: does the `2nd charge` always have `#2` and so on..for other charges?

Comment: I hope you're going to be normalizing your tables after cleaning it up.

Comment: yes, at times #2 , #3 etc... thats why I'd liek to delete #2 and to the right..

Comment: This woirked great but left the hash mark.. but oither than that it was great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` in combination with `substring` and `update` the column.

```
update criminals set charge1 = 
replace(charge1,substring(charge1, charindex('#',charge1), len(charge1)),'')
where charindex('#',charge1) > 0
```

Comment: I ran the unedited tsql and it worked great! I see you added so that it only runs on the columns that have the # sign... but either way it worked great thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions and perform a `UPDATE` operation like below

```
update criminal 
set charge = substring(charge,1, charindex('#', charge))
where some_column = filter;
```

Include a `WHERE` condition in case you want to update to a specific row. If all the records `CHARGE` column have same data format then without `WHERE` clause as well should work fine.